# DocuSign Radio button conditional field

Tags: conditional-statements, field, docusignapi

I am working on POC for DocuSign functionality. The one of few requirements is conditional field. I am able to get conditional field visibility of another text box working with Check box and Text box. The DocuSign documentation says "You can apply conditional logic to the following field types:Checkbox, Radio Button, Drop-down,Text". I am not able to see TabLabel property for Radio group or radio button. Is there any sample available to demonstrate this functionality. Or at least if it is possible or not.

Thanks

Comment: Note: I am using DocuSign SDK from Nuget for checking and I am getting following error - Error calling CreateEnvelope: {
  "errorCode": "CONDITIONALTAB_HAS_INVALID_PARENT",
  "message": "A conditional tab references an invalid parent. Parent label must match another tab. Only one parent allowed. Signature tabs may not be parent tabs."
} if I tried to set ConditionalParentLabel and ConditionalParentValue to other radio group /. radio button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define a [RadioGroup](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeTabs/create/#definitions--radioGroup) tab and set the **GroupName**.

You can then set **ConditionalParentLabel** on another tab to display it  conditionally. The **ConditionalParentValue** is the Value of the parent tab that controls this tab’s visibility.

In the following example when the RadioButton is selected as "Y" the TextBox is displayed.

See the full sample [here](https://gist.github.com/codingdawg/1ecbed65aaf705871d5a63e8ccb6ec7f).

```
        var textTab = new Text()
        {
            DocumentId = "1",
            PageNumber = "1",
            RecipientId = "1",
            XPosition = "100",
            YPosition = "100",
            Height = "11",
            Width = "42",
            ConditionalParentLabel = "RadioGroupTest",
            ConditionalParentValue = "Y"
        };

        var radioGroup = new RadioGroup()
        {
            GroupName = "RadioGroupTest",
            DocumentId = "1",
            RecipientId = "1",
            Radios = new List<Radio>()
            {
                new Radio()
                {
                    PageNumber = "1",
                    XPosition = "100",
                    YPosition = "70",
                    Value = "Y"
                },
                new Radio()
                {
                    PageNumber = "1",
                    XPosition = "130",
                    YPosition = "70",
                    Value = "N"
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: Is there any way to just specify the radio group.  The radios know which group they belong to.  Why do we need to go through all the trouble of specifying the location of each radio?  I have searched and searched but the best alternative we've come up with is anchor text.